# How to aggregate two results according to one filed in SQL?

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a `attemps.cvs`, its format is

```
(problem_id, people_id, answer);
```

A `people.cvs`, its format is

```
(people_id, last_name, first_name);
```

A `prolems.cvs`, its format is

```
(problem_id, answer)
```

After I crate three tables and populate data into them, I want to find **How many problems has one people answered, and answered correctly?** .

- How many problems has one answered ?

  (Join **people** and **attemps**)

  SELECT first_name, last_name, count(people.people_id) FROM people,
  attempts WHERE people.people_id=attempts.people_id GROUP BY
  first_name, last_name, people.people_id);
- How many problems has one answered correctly ?

  (Join those three) Add **problems.answer=attemps.answer** to the `SQL` 's `WHERE` clause.

Question: how to get the two infos within one single `SQL` ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you want to know how many problems have one answer, you don't need to join with the "people" table. The following query given all the problems that have only one answer.

```
SELECT problem_id
FROM attempts
GROUP BY problem_id
HAVING count(*) = 1;
```

To get the problem that has one answer and answered correctly:

```
SELECT problems.problem_id
FROM attempts, problems
WHERE attempts.problem_id = problems.problem_id
and attemps.answer = problems.answer
and problem_id IN 
(
    SELECT problem_id
    FROM attempts
    GROUP BY problem_id
    HAVING count(*) = 1
);
```

Comment: I want the **count** of one answered, and the **count**  answered correctly.

Comment: Now I'm a bit confused... are those two things separate? You mean you want the count of problems with one answer separate from the count of problems with the correct answer?

Comment: If that's what you're looking for, I have posted another answer.

Answer (score 0):

This query prints the number of problems with one answer and the number of problems answered correctly:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT count(problem_id) as OneAnswer
FROM attempts
GROUP BY problem_id
HAVING count(*) = 1) as OA,
(SELECT count(problem_id) as AnsweredCorrectly
FROM problems
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT problem_id FROM attempts 
             WHERE attempts.problem_id = problems.problem_id 
             and attemps.answer = problems.answer)) as AC;
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer should print the number of times a People has Answered each question and how many times they have gotten the correct Answer.

Note : Slight typo made earlier - sorry.

```
SELECT b.people_id,
       COUNT(b.answer),
       c.CountCorrect
FROM attempts b,
     (SELECT a.people_id,
             COUNT( a.people_id )
      FROM attempts a,
           problems pr
      WHERE a.problem_id = pr.problem_id AND
            a.answer = pr.answer
      GROUP BY a.people_id) c
WHERE b.people_id = c.people_id
GROUP BY b.people_id;
```

This answer should print the number of times a People has Answered questions and how many times they have gotten correct Answers.

```
SELECT b.people_id,
       COUNT(b.answer),
       c.CountCorrect
FROM attempts b,
     (SELECT a.people_id,
             COUNT( a.people_id )
      FROM attempts a,
           problems pr
      WHERE a.answer = pr.answer
      GROUP BY a.people_id) c
WHERE b.people_id = c.people_id
GROUP BY b.people_id;
```